# Web.Config transformation not applied after publish

Tags: visual-studio-2015, web-config, transformation

I found a few similar questions but none that seemed to help me.

I have the following in my web.config:

```
<appSettings configSource=".\ConfigDEV\AppSettings.xml" />
  <connectionStrings configSource=".\ConfigDEV\ConnectionStrings.xml" />
  <applicationSettings>
    <StarLight.Properties.Settings configSource=".\ConfigDEV\TaxonomySettings.xml" />
    <Stikeman.MatterDB.Library.Properties.Settings configSource=".\ConfigDEV\MatterDBSettings.xml" />
  </applicationSettings>
```

I have the following in my Web.Release.config:

```
<appSettings configSource="__AppSettingsPath__" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(configSource)" />
  <connectionStrings configSource="__ConnectionStringsPath__" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(configSource)" />
  <applicationSettings>
    <StarLight.Properties.Settings configSource="__TaxonomySettingsPath__" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(configSource)" />
    <Stikeman.MatterDB.Library.Properties.Settings configSource="__MatterDBSettingsPath__" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(configSource)" />
  </applicationSettings>
```

If I publish the solution in VS2015 (using the Publish command), the web.config does not get transformed and the original configSource values are still present.

What am I missing here?

Any help appreciated.

thanks,
KS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to replace configSource you should remove the xdt:Locator. You can test  by right click on .\ConfigDEV\AppSettings.xml file and choose preview transformation.

```
<appSettings configSource="__AppSettingsPath__" xdt:Transform="Replace"  />
  <connectionStrings configSource="__ConnectionStringsPath__" xdt:Transform="Replace"  />
  <applicationSettings>
    <StarLight.Properties.Settings configSource="__TaxonomySettingsPath__" xdt:Transform="Replace"  />
    <Stikeman.MatterDB.Library.Properties.Settings configSource="__MatterDBSettingsPath__" xdt:Transform="Replace"  />
  </applicationSettings>
```

I had the same problem and had to remove Locator in order to get the replacement.